# Sorting multidimensional array in third level

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

In the array below you can see that the order of 'listElemId' differs from the three first elements in the array. What I want is them to be in order (listElem 1,2,3). 'listElemPoints' should of course follow.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks in advance!

```
$listArray {
  [0] {
      [0] {
          ["listElemId"] = 2    // <- should be 1
          ["listElemPoints"] = 1 }
      [1] {
          ["listElemId"] = 3    // <- should be 2
          ["listElemPoints"] = 2 }
      [2] {
        ["listElemId"] = 1      // <- should be 3
        ["listElemPoints"] = 3 }
      }
  [1] {
      [0] {
          ["listElemId"] = 3    // <- should be 1
          ["listElemPoints"] = 1 }
      [1] {
          ["listElemId"] = 2    // <- correct
          ["listElemPoints"] = 2 }
      [2] {
          ["listElemId"] = 1    // <- should be 3
          ["listElemPoints"] = 3 }
      }
  [2] {
      [0] {
          ["listElemId"] = 3    // <- should be 1
          ["listElemPoints"] = 1 }
      [1] {
          ["listElemId"] = 1    // <- should be 2
          ["listElemPoints"] = 2 }
      [2] {
          ["listElemId"] = 2    // <- should be 3
          ["listElemPoints"] = 3 }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
foreach ($listArray as &$arr) {
  uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['listElemId'] > $b['listElemId'];
  });
}
```